# Haskell on ARM Beagleboard

Tags: haskell, beagleboard

I would like to use the Haskell GHC / Haskell Platform on [Beagleboards](http://beagleboard.org/) that are based on ARM OMAP. Is there any way to do that within short term but without me having to try to cross compile first e.g. LLVM and then GHC etc. for a couple of weeks?

Comment: On my ARM platform I just used debian's unregistered GHC build for the Carmel platforms - no problems.  Things are bound to be better now that was have an official ARM backend (see link in the answer).

Comment: Where is the link between Carmel and ARM? Isn't that two fundamentally different circuits?

Comment: Sorry, my phone auto-completed oddly.  I was referring to the [Debian Armel platform](http://www.debian.org/ports/arm/) (little-endian ARM, which is how most ARM platforms are).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I nearly forgot I made a [post](http://tommd.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/ghc-on-arm/) about using the Debian Armel (unregistered) build on a beagleboard like device.

Luckily we'll be able to have a registered build soon enough (see this [link](http://ghcarm.wordpress.com/) from jmg's answer).  I suspect you could get the Debian unregistered GHC build, install LLVM 3.0, and build GHC HEAD (which includes the linked ARM support - note it isn't functioning perfectly quite yet), thus obtaining a registered build.  I don't see why you think this would require any cross compilation.

Answer (score 3):

I have no hands on experience with GHC on ARM. But are you aware of the following page? http://ghcarm.wordpress.com/

Comment: Yes, I concluded from here (http://ghcarm.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/current-status-merged-into-ghc-head/)  that this meant some heavy cross compiling.